# CentOS 7 のパーティションの分け方

Tags: linux, centos

ハードディスクが 2 個あり、A と B だとします。

1. AとBのそれぞれに CentOS 7 を入れて、AとBどちらからでも起動できるようにする
2. AからB、BからAのように異なるパーティションのデータを見えるようにする

どうすればよいですか？

Comment: 質問の「2」ですが、どのように見えれば目的に叶いますか？例えば、OS:A の 「/」が OS:B の「/hogehoge/」 にマウントできれば問題無いでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AとBのそれぞれに CentOS 7 を入れて、AとBどちらからでも起動できるようにする

EFI が前提ですが EFI ブートエントリーに A，B  それぞれの ブートローダを登録すれば マザーボードの 起動デバイスの選択で A, B どちらからでも起動できます。以下 Disk A = sda、Disk B = sdb とします。

sda に OS-A をインストール

```
インストール先
  /boot       sda2
  /boot/efi   sda1
  /           sda の好きなところに (※１)
  swap        sda の好きなところに (※１)
```

sdb に OS-B をインストール

```
インストール先
  /boot       sdb2
  /boot/efi   sdb1
  /           sdb の好きなところに (※２)
  swap        sdb の好きなところに (※２)
```

(※1) 今回は sda 上に Logical Volume「centos7a」を作成
(※2) 今回は sdb 上の Logical Volume「centos7b」を作成

インストールしたOSにログインして EFI Boot Manager のエントリを確認

```
# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0004
BootOrder: 0004,0005,0000,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* EFI DVD/CDROM ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1,1)ATAPI(1,0,0)
Boot0001* EFI Hard Drive        ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(d,0)SATA(0,0,0)
Boot0002* EFI Hard Drive 1      ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(d,0)SATA(1,0,0)
Boot0003* EFI Internal Shell    MM(b,3fc4f000,3ffbefff)FvFile(7c04a583-933e-4f1c-ad65-e05268d0b4d1)
Boot0004* CentOS        HDD(1,800,64000,bd4164f0-88fc-4d71-b3ee-64b246027aab)File(\EFI\centos\shim.efi)
```

デフォルトのエントリを消して「CentOS7 A」と「CentOS7 B」というエントリを作ります。

```
# efibootmgr -b 4 -B     ← 0004 のエントリを消す
# efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l '\EFI\centos\shim.efi' -L 'CentoOS7 A'
# efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdb -p 1 -l '\EFI\centos\shim.efi' -L 'CentoOS7 B'
```

最終的に次のようになります。

```
# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0004
BootOrder: 0005,0004,0000,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* EFI DVD/CDROM ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1,1)ATAPI(1,0,0)
Boot0001* EFI Hard Drive        ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(d,0)SATA(0,0,0)
Boot0002* EFI Hard Drive 1      ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(d,0)SATA(1,0,0)
Boot0003* EFI Internal Shell    MM(b,3fc4f000,3ffbefff)FvFile(7c04a583-933e-4f1c-ad65-e05268d0b4d1)
Boot0004* CentOS7 A     HDD(1,800,64000,e2f4a240-71e1-45da-9822-1dc34e42247f)File(\EFI\centos\shim.efi)
Boot0005* CentOS7 B     HDD(1,800,64000,bd4164f0-88fc-4d71-b3ee-64b246027aab)File(\EFI\centos\shim.efi)
```

再起動して、マザーボードの 起動デバイスを選ぶメニューを開きます。
マザーボードによって 操作方法が違うのでマニュアル等で確認してください。
( F8とかF10、F12あたりのキーだと思います )

起動デバイスの一覧に `efibootmgr` で登録したエントリが表示されるので
`CentOS7 A` か `CentOS7 B` を選択して OS（と言うかそれぞれのGrub）を起動します。

> AからB、BからAのように異なるパーティションのデータを見えるようにする

OS-A から B のデバイスをマウントします。

1. マウントポイトを作成

   - `mkdir /centos7b`
2. B の 論理ボリューム または パーティションをマウント

   - `mount -t xfs /dev/mapper/centos7b-root /centos7b`
3. 起動時に自動マウントしたいなら /etc/fstab に記述

   - `vi /etc/fstab`

     > /dev/mapper/centos7b-root /centos7b  xfs   defaults  0 0

OS-B から A をマウントします。

Answer (score 0):

RAID1的なものを求めているのでは、ないとして。

Aに、CentOSをinstallする。
Bにも、CentOSをinstallする。

で、2つめのCentOSをインストールすれば、普通は、boot selectorのGRUBのメニューに、boot対象の２つのCentOSが、載っている。

で、普通は、FSの問題はないから、それぞれの/etc/fstab の記述をいじってやれば、Aでbootしても、BのFSはmountされてるし、Bでbootしても、AのFSは、mountできる。

しかし、こういうシステムは、あんまり感心しない。というのも、今、Aでbootしているのか、Bでbootしているのか、間違えて、消してはいけないファイルを消したりしかねないので。